# unable to extract data in ms-sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am trying to retrieve data from tables and my script looks like this->

```
SELECT 
            e.*, 
            c.ClientName 
        FROM 
            Entities e WITH(nolock) 
            JOIN Clients c WITH(nolock) ON c.ClientId = e.ClientId 
        WHERE 
            e.ClientId = 222222
```

part of output is->

```
entityid                   clientid                 version                clientname

1                           222222                   1                     first
2                           222222                    1                    second
```

what i need to get is for this clientid, fetch all entities with their latest version.

what i have written->

```
SELECT 
            e.*, 
            c.ClientName 
        FROM 
            Entities e WITH(nolock) 
            JOIN Clients c WITH(nolock) ON c.ClientId = e.ClientId 
        WHERE 
            e.[Version] = (SELECT MAX([Version]) FROM Entities b WHERE e.EntityId=b.EntityId)  AND

            e.ClientId = 222222
```

what this gives me->

```
   entityid                   clientid                 version                clientname

1                           222222                   1                     first
```

which is wrong. can someone help?

Comment: Is there a *good* reason you are using `NOLOCK` here?

Comment: Presumably there is another row in your table `Entities` where `entityid` has a value of `2` and `version` has a value greater than `1`; perhaps for a different `clientid`.

Comment: yes true. so what do i do?

Comment: Correlate your subquery on the `clientid` too? There's too little information for me to guess; especially as there's no expected results and minimal sample data.

Comment: pls help dude. it is very important. just guess and i will try to see if it works

Comment: [so] isn't for guesses... If it's important, improve the question so that users here can help. Also, please don't call me "dude".

Comment: FYI - not everyone is a "dude"

Comment: @SMor i cant figure out how to use it in mine. a little help please.

Comment: What they are trying to tell you is that if you want help, you need to help us first. We need more information before we can help. Providing us with sample data and expected result would really help us, until we have that it is very difficult for anyone to help you.

Comment: i completely understand and next time i will take care of this. for now this issue has been solved @GuidoG

Comment: If this is no longer an issue, then please delete this question. Thank you